# Use only one BufferedReader object to read multiple files in java

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I have multiple BufferedReader objects based in Java. I have declared many `BufferedReader` objects for reading each separate file, but the problem is how can I have one object only for reading files in order to loop with `for` each? Here is my sample source code and it is better to reduce it.

```
FileInputStream f1 = new FileInputStream(filepath);
BufferedReader b1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(f1));

FileInputStream f2 = new FileInputStream(filepath);
BufferedReader b2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(f2));

FileInputStream f3 = new FileInputStream(filepath);
BufferedReader b3 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(f3));
```

Comment: When you generalize code to reduce repetition, think about what's changing. In this case, the filename changes. Refactor the code by creating a method that does 'the task' and pass it 'the thing that changes'.

Comment: What are you asking? How to write a `for` loop?

Comment: I am asking which is the best way to reduce duplication of code such as multiple instances of BufferedReader?

Comment: In this example here the easiest way to reduce code duplication would be to create a loop and then place the file reading algorithm inside the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a small helper method, like

```
private List<String> readFile(whatever)
```

and then call that method in a loop. The idea of the BufferedReader is to wrap around *one* thing. There is no point in thinking about resetting that thing. To be used something like:

```
for (String fileName : fileNames) {
  fileContents.addAll(readFile(fileName));
}
```

But the exact nature of that loop and the ideal design of that helper method depends on the details of your requirements.

Comment: In my opinion, you are absolutely correct in the declaration of your method. Actually, my problem is how to make a loop in order to read each file separately. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the file path to argument and create a list with all the filepaths and not put it the list manually. Example for the forementioned txt :

```
File[] files = new File(args[0].replace("\\", "\\\\")).listFiles(new FilenameFilter() { @Override public boolean accept(File dir, String name) { return name.endsWith(".txt"); } });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Try-With-Resource as below (on java8): [REF](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

```
    List<String> filePathList = Arrays.asList("./a.txt", "./b.txt");
    filePathList.forEach(filePath -> {
        try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));){
            // Do something with bufferedReader
            // bufferedReader will be cleaned automatically in the end of try-catch block 
        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```